# Auto layout removing from superview doesn't update

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to make an UILabel grow by removing the constraints via removeFromSuperview. The text field 1 is removed. But it still doesn't let the UILabel grow in width. I have attached the sample code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6lve438gqv3qqs/testAutoLayout%202.zip?dl=0) for reference. Its completely on the story board.

Here is my ViewDidLoad method:

```
  self.label1.text = @"label 1";
  self.label2.text = @"label 2";
  self.textfield1.text = @"text field 1";
  self.textfield2.text = @"text field 2";
  [self.textfield1 removeFromSuperview];
```

I don't want to have an IBOutlet of the constraints and update it on the code. I'm trying to get this on the storyboard for once.

Comment: Maybe you need to call `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your label 2 is depending on its position to textfield 1, and you want label 2 to grow to occupy the space of textfield 1 when you remove textfield 1. However, since label 2 is (say, 20 pixels to the right of textfield 1), when you remove textfield 1, that constraint is removed (it is now invalid as textfield 1 no longer exists!) and a default one is generated relative to the superview.

There is a simple solution but it is rather imperfect - instead of removing from superview set the width of textfield 1 to 0. You will then see a change in label 2's position.

For more control however, I think you still have to `IBOutlet` the constraint.

Comment: I want label2 to occupy the space of textfield1.

Comment: It is still the same principle. I'll update my answer if it bothers you.

Comment: I already did - however if I'm getting the layout wrong, I might need some layout diagram to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

With the following technique, instead of removing the textfield, you can just set its text to nil. Its intrinsic content size will then have zero width, and your label will expand to fill the additional space.

- Constrain both the label and textfield to their superview's nearest edge (i.e. 1 constraint each), and constrain their vertical position as you wish.
- Add a horizontal space constraint between the label and textfield (e.g. with a constant gap of 8 points).
- Increment the textfield's compression resistance priority, and its content hugging priority (both horizontal).

Im assuming your layout looks something like this:

`|[label][textField]|`